# How to prove that a union of cardinals is a cardinal

Tags: set-theory

I have this question:

Let $\omega_1$ the least uncountable cardinal, and for all $n \in \omega$, $n \geq 1$. Let $\omega_{n+1}$ the least cardianal greater than $\omega_n$. Show that $$\bigcup_{n \in \omega}\omega_n$$ is a cardinal.

My try: Let $f_n : \omega_n \rightarrow A_n $ a bijectionfor all $n \in \omega$. And let  $$F_n :\bigcup_{n \in \omega}\omega_n \rightarrow \bigcup_{n \in \omega}A_n$$. $F(x) = f_n(x)$, where $n = min\{ n: x \in A_n\}$. An d prove that $F$ is a bijection. But I'm not have sucess.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\eta:=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}\omega_n$$
is an ordinal. It is in fact the smallest ordinal greater than $\omega_n$ for all $n\in\omega$. If $\xi$ is an ordinal, $\xi<\eta$, it is by definition *not* greater than $\omega_n$ for all $n\in\omega$.

Can you get the rest of the way on your own now?